# pass array as parameters in function

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parameter-passing

I have a function need to pass an array and the array value will be modified in that function. I implement it as follows, but the values in the array does not change after the function is called. Could any one help me with this? Thanks!

This is where I call the function, `socket.Receive(sender,buffer,sizeof(buffer))`. The variable `buffer` does not get the right value.

```
while ( true )
{
    Address sender;
    unsigned char buffer[256];
    int bytes_read = socket.Receive( sender, buffer, sizeof( buffer) );
    if ( !bytes_read )
        break;
    printf("%d\n",buffer[92]);

}
```

This is the code of function `socket.Receive()`

```
int Socket::Receive( Address & sender, 
                    void*  data, 
                    int size )
{
        unsigned char packet_data[256];

        unsigned int max_packet_size = 
            sizeof( packet_data );

#if PLATFORM == PLATFORM_WINDOWS
        typedef int socklen_t;
#endif

        sockaddr_in from;    
        socklen_t fromLength = sizeof( from );

        size = recvfrom( handle, 
            (char*)packet_data, 
            max_packet_size,
            0, 
            (sockaddr*)&from, 
            &fromLength );

        data = packet_data;
        unsigned int from_address = ntohl( from.sin_addr.s_addr );
        unsigned int from_port = ntohs( from.sin_port );

    return size;
}
```

Comment: You realize that `packet_data[256]` is a local scope variable array, don't you?

Comment: What value _does_ it get, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = packet_data;
```

On this line you're assigning to `data` but the parameter that `Receive` takes is a local copy of a pointer. It needs to take a reference if you are trying to mutate the argument being passed:

```
int Socket::Receive( Address & sender, 
                    void*&  data, // <-- reference to a pointer
                    int size )
```

And like @DrewDormann said, the assignment doesn't copy the data from `packet_data` to `data`, but rather changes the address the `data` points to to the address of `packet_data`. The consequence is that when you attempt to derefrerence `buffer` later on, you will get Undefined Behavior for accessing an already destroyed object.

Instead, should use `memcpy` to copy the data:

```
#include <cstring>
std::memcpy(data, packet_data, size);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have several bugs, but the problem you mention stems from this line.

```
        data = packet_data;
```

This line does **not** copy the entire `packet_data` array.  It only overwrites the pointer `data` with a new address.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because you declare "unsigned char packet_data[256];" on the stack of your function and you do not copy from it the bytes to your "data" parameter. Use memcpy to copy contents of "packet_data" into "data". What you are doing instead you are assigning "data" to "packet_data", when you do that "data" will point to the same memory as "packet_data" does. But as soon as the function exits, "packet_data" is being freed, so it's contents become garbage. Hence you do not see the data in your "data" pointer. Hope this was helpful.